# Obtener el valor de un td por medio de x columna y x fila

Tags: javascript, tablas

Tengo el siguiente código que me regresa el index de la fila y la columna

```
function onDataBound(e) {
            var grid = $("#presidencialistas").data("kendoGrid");
            $(grid.tbody).on("click", "td", function (e) {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
                //var colIdx = $("td", row).index(this);
                var colIdx = 0;
                //alert(rowIdx + '-' + colIdx);
                var index = value();
                return index;
            });
```

El resultado por ejemplo es el siguiente Ej 3-0

Lo que necesito es obtener el valor o el texto del campo que se encuentra en esa pocision

alguna idea

Comment: debes colocar todo el codigo! o un ejemplo mas completo y el resultado esperado!

Answer (score 0):

quizá este código te ayude o te de una manito, en tu caso si ya sabes a cual `td` se le dió ***click***, entonces sólo obtén ese valor con el método `.text()`, algo así: `return index.text();` .Te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```js
$('body #tabla').on('click', 'td', function(){
        alert($(this).text())
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" cellpadding="5" id="tabla">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Nombres</td>
        <td>Apellidos</td>
        <td>Cosas</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>nombre1</td>
      <td>apellido1</td>
      <td>cosa1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>nombre2</td>
      <td>apellido2</td>
      <td>cosa2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>nombre3</td>
      <td>apellido3</td>
      <td>cosa3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```